# Valgrind with options

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

If I run `valgrind`

```
valgrind --show-reachable=yes /home/costa/Desktop/zadacha_2_7/main.c
```

it says that I have *Still Reachable*, so I understand that it means that there is some memory, which wasn't deallocated.

Here is `valgrind`'s output:

```
==2841== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2841== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2841== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2841== Command: /home/costa/Desktop/zadacha_2_7/main.c
==2841== /home/costa/Desktop/zadacha_2_7/main.c: 5: 
         /home/costa/Desktop/zadacha_2_7/main.c: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
==2841== 
==2841== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2841==     in use at exit: 1,084 bytes in 68 blocks
==2841==   total heap usage: 70 allocs, 2 frees, 2,100 bytes allocated
==2841== 
==2841== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2841==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2841==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2841==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2841==    still reachable: 1,084 bytes in 68 blocks
==2841==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2841== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2841== 
==2841== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2841== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So, I'd like to see these reachable blocks (that are not shown), how can I do that?

I don't get it, why doesn't `valgrind` show anything about these blocks with option `--show-reachable=yes`?

Comment: `valgrind` should be run on executable. You even have compilation errors. Fix then, build your app, then run `valgrind` on the executable. Also, _still reachable_ is not a big deal.

Comment: @KirilKirov, I didn't get it, where are the compilation errors? There are 0 in ERROR SUMMARY . And now I am running a program and valgrind at the same time, but there is no result( Couldn't you explain me more wider? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Before the summary sections, there's `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. So, before `valgrind`, compile the program (with `gcc` or something else) and run it to see if it works. Then, after this is done, run `valgrind` again, BUT instead of specifying `xxxxx/main.c` (s argument passed to vagrind), add the built executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf the output of valgrind you copied here:

```
==2841== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```